# How to disable chunked encoding for JSON responses in Laravel?

Tags: json, http, laravel-5, transfer-encoding

I'm returning an array from a controller method in Laravel. Laravel interprets this to mean I want to send JSON, which is great, but it doesn't set the `Content-Length` and instead uses `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.

My responses are tiny, so I don't want to chunk them. How can I disable chunked encoding + enable Content-Length?

I'm using nginx for the server, if relevant.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @roundtheworld Nope.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me in Laravel (5.8) was to add a header do disable `Content-Encoding`. The problem is that Nginx (10) was configured to compress the output using `gzip` which adds `Content-Encoding:gzip`, `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` and removes `Content-Length` header. But by adding that header Nginx bypasses compression and won't make those changes to the header.

```
$headers = [
        "Content-Length" => strlen($responseJson),
        "Content-Encoding" => "disabled",
    ];
```

Answer (score -1):

My solution is adding `content-length` headers to the response, then `chunked-transfer` will be replaced

```
    $responseJson = json_encode($response);

    $headers = [
        "Content-Length" => strlen($responseJson),
    ];

    return response($responseJson, 200, $headers);
```

you can try it with postman

---

for JSON content, just add content type in headers

```
    $headers = [
        "Content-Length" => strlen($responseJson),
        "Content-Type" => "application/json",
    ];
```

Comment: Is that setting the correct `Content-Type` (application/json)?

Comment: by default it is `text/html`, you can set it yourself