# How can I use chunked transfer encoding in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, rest, http, http-1.1

Good day. I am wondering if I can use chunked transfer encoding(further CTE) in API response? I have large data in the database and I need to transfer it to the client in one request. I've read a lot about the CTE mechanism, but I could not find how to implement this, unfortunately.

One important thing to mention: no pagination. It is supposed to be an autonomous system which returns data back to the client's endpoint, not to the web page.

As I mentioned, the data is stored in the database. The only problem is how to split the data into segments(chunks) and send them in one API response (one-by-one).

Thanks.

Comment: I don't quite understand what chunked transfer encoding has to do with the problem. What do you mean by "split the data into segments"? What problems have you run into with simply sending the entire result set back? Exactly how many records are we talking about?

Comment: It could contain 10 records,for example, but each has a json field with 100k+ entries.

Comment: So it would be perfectly to stream each entry one-by-one as a chunk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my specific case I've solved my problem by using this code(example):

```php
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse;

$response = new StreamedResponse();
$response->setCallback(function () {
    var_dump('Hello World');
    flush();
    sleep(2);
    var_dump('Hello World');
    flush();
});
$response->send();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be interested in the chunk method on the Query Builder.

> ## Chunking Results
>
> If you need to work with thousands of database records, consider using
>   the chunk method. This method retrieves a small chunk of the results
>   at a time and feeds each chunk into a Closure for processing. This
>   method is very useful for writing Artisan commands that process
>   thousands of records. For example, let's work with the entire users
>   table in chunks of 100 records at a time:

```
$response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\StreamedResponse(function() {
    $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    DB::table('users')->orderBy('id')->chunk(100, function ($users) use($handle) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            fputs($handle, json_encode($user));
        }
    });

    fclose($handle);
});

return $response;
```

Further Reading: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#chunking-results

### Chunked Transfer Encoding

As far as I'm aware Laravel [does this by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41657052/how-to-disable-chunked-encoding-for-json-responses-in-laravel) if you return a JSON response.

### UPDATE:

My solution was unnecessarily convoluted and complex. I've removed the `StreamedResponse` since there really wasn't any need of it. See updated example below.

```
$json_response = collect();

DB::table('users')->orderBy('id')->chunk(100, function ($users) use($json_response) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $json_response->push($user);
    }
});

return $json_response->toJson();
```

Comment: About the first paragraph: you misunderstood me. I meant to SEND data in chunks, not to GET.

Comment: About the second paragraph: the data is still transfered as usual, not chunked. So I asked you to help me creating a function to convert Eloquent model into chunked result.

Comment: If you want to SEND data, then I would personally setup an endpoint for the user where you use the chunk method on the query builder - whether you set this up on your eloquent model or do it in the controller is your choice - and you will be able to `chunk` it down to be manageable by the client. I really do believe that what you're looking for is the method i showcased in my answer. To better understand your predicament, maybe you can tell me - if this is the case - why you can't use the above method.

Comment: I cannot get the point of the first method. Loop though in order to do what? Nothing... That method is used to just chunk Eloquent models, not the API response. The CTE mechanism does the following(as I got it): it converts the data into the bytecode, but previously it converts each string into a combination of line breaks, data length and the actual data. It sounds complicated(Wikipedia explains it better). But the upper method is just chunking the database records.

Comment: @Nod I added a new example, I hope this helps you. You might be need to custom headers to indicate that it's a JSON response, but other than that it should be fine. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this won’t work. Here are the reasons: in the last example you are just pushing entries to a collection and returning collection as a JSON string. This won’t change the behavior at all. Personally I am returning the result with response()->json(), so there is no need to convert array to json and pass it to the response(redundant steps).